# CSS "background-image: linear-gradient" makes unwanted repeating color stripes with 180 degrees

Tags: html, css, background-image, linear-gradients, repeating-linear-gradient

When i use:

`body {background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, grey 100%);}`

The result is as expected:
[image]

But when i change the angle to 180' or 0' it makes stripes:
[image]

Well if this was what i wanted, i'd just use `repeating-linear-gradient()`

- I tried searching it on internet, but results was always about using `repeating-linear-gradient()`. Rather than "Im having trouble with unexpected linear stripes"
- I poked around with the angle, it only gives me this result when it is 0 or 180 degrees. lets say when the cosinus is 0.

Comment: min-height:100% on the html element is what you need

Answer (score 3):

I figured that the problem is about the unknown height of the body element. So it repeats the small heighted `background-image`.
[image]
is the result with 500px height.

And the resultant solution is:

```
body, html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,white 0%, grey 100%);
    }
```

[image]
It works like a charm.

I also realised that the tutorial i was following was showing it and i missed it cause i was focused on fixing it.

Comment: Preferably set min-height instead of height on body (just in case the content is taller than screen).